# How i can divide the string with IP and ports?

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have such a line:

`176.32.37.27:777754.38.156.202:777751.68.208.5:7777`

How can the cycle inferred from this string of IP ports by using the split function or similar? To make it so:

`176.32.37.27:7777
54.38.156.202:7777
51.68.208.5:7777`

the ports are the same only because they have 4 digits

Comment: Something to start with: `"176.32.37.27:777754.38.156.202:777751.68.208.5:7777".split("(?<=:\\d{4})")` ==> `String[3] { "176.32.37.27:7777", "54.38.156.202:7777", "51.68.208.5:7777" }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you know your port's length will always be 4, you can split based on a lookbehind that takes the colon and 4 digits:

```
String test = "176.32.37.27:777754.38.156.202:777751.68.208.5:7777";
System.out.println(
   Arrays.toString(
       test.split("(?<=:\\d{4})")
   )
);
```

**Output**

```
[176.32.37.27:7777, 54.38.156.202:7777, 51.68.208.5:7777]
```

**See also**

Lookbehind in Java pattern [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Thanks! But when I want to get the first value from the array, the Array type expected error pops up; found: 'java.lang.Stringэ. I declared a class for the variable "arrayServers", but nothing has changed

`String arrayServers = Arrays.toString(getServers.get().split("(?<=:\\d{4})"));
Log.i(LOG_TAG,""+arrayServers['0']);`

Comment: `Arrays.toString` only converts the array to its `String` representation, in my example, for handy printing. You cannot access a `String` portion by array indices. TL;DR You just need: `String[] arrayServers = getServers.get().split("(?<=:\\d{4})");`

Comment: @Gavin you can. Up to `65535`. But OP's use case seems to imply 4 digit ports only.

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant to delete that as I reread the post and spotted the size limit.  Sorry my bad.

Comment: @Gavin no worries, that was a legit question imo.

Comment: @Mena I gave you a plus for reputation. Can you please tell me for one how to do so, only with an associative array where it will be displayed [PI => 176.32.37.27 PORT => 7777, PI => 54.38.156.202 PORT => 7777, PI => 51.68.208.5 PORT => 7777]. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @sha512boo the java data structure you're looking for is a `Map`. Specifically and for simplicity, it can be a `HashMap<String, String>` (assuming you have no sorting/ordering/concurrency requirements and are happy to represent both IPs and ports as `String`s). You can basically iterate over the `String[]` you already have, split by colon to separate IPs from ports, then put each IP as key and port as value of your `Map`. If you have difficulties getting there, I recommend posting a new question with your attempt and desired result, optionally linking to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for split the IP Address.

```
String str = "176.32.37.27:777754.38.156.202:777751.68.208.5:7777";

String ipAdds[] = str.split("(?<=:\\d{4})");

for (String ipAdd: ipAdds)
     System.out.println(ipAdd);
```